# heroku node mongodb, `require is not defined`

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

I have a question about running my seedDB.js locally and in heroku. Currently I have:

- `npm start` running with status: connected to development database
- `webpack --w` running with no errors
- `mongod` running with status:

  - `MongoDB starting : pid=28871 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db`
  - `waiting for connections on port 27017`

But when I run `mongo host:port/db -u user -p pass yourSeedFile.js`, I got:

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.6
connecting to: localhost:27017/appName
2017-01-09T11:02:22.605-0800 E QUERY    [thread1] ReferenceError: require is not defined :
@yourSeedFile.js:1:5
```

Any suggestions on what is going on plz?

Comment: Looks to me like it's trying to execute the .js file natively rather than with Node.

Comment: why? I have npm running

Comment: When you execute `yourSeedFile.js`, it's running in the context of Mongo, not Node. So when you're using `require()` inside `yourSeedFile.js`, it'll fail because Mongo isn't running under Node.

Comment: so you mean i need first run `node` then execute yourSeedFile.js?

Comment: Without seeing what it's doing, I don't know. But if you're using `require()`, it'll need to be executed with Node.